# Where is Inspect Screenshot button in Hierarchy Viewer?

Tags: android, hierarchyviewer

I cannot see the Inspect Screenshot button. I think it should be next to the Refresh and Load View Hierarchy buttons.
Any help?
[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can add this tool by doing so in the Device Monitor window :

```
go to Window -> Open Perspective ... => Pixel Perfect
```